# database keeps getting deleted - couchdb, nodeJS, nano & Bluebird

Tags: node.js, couchdb, bluebird, couchdb-nano

I am using couchdb, and I am running the following code with the following packages (nano & Bluebird)

```
nano = nano(uri)
var db_name = Promise.promisifyAll(nano.db.use(resources.db.name))

exports.db_init = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var temp_doc = {'Hello' : 'World'}
        db_name.insertAsync(temp_doc)
            .then(function (body) {
                return db_name.destroyAsync(body.id, body.rev)
            })
            .then(function (body) {
                resolve(body)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                reject(err)
            })
    })
}
```

When I call the above function, I see the body in the console, however when I view it in futon, the db gets deleted.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's getting deleted, or you just never see it in Futon?

Comment: Could the problem be that you're not replicating the db like [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html)?

Comment: @Pushkin I am sure I am not replicating, I get the info in the console that the document has been inserted and deleted but when I refresh futon, I can no longer view the db.

Comment: And you could see the db (in futon) before the function was called, right?

Comment: @Pushkin yes.  I can see it before the function is called.